# Event handler of another frame not getting called - wxWidgets

Tags: c++, eventhandler

Good day to all,

I'm working on a C++ program using `wxWidgets` wherein a frame has a button named "Calibrate Button" which is used to calibrate HSV values using a trackbar. When the user selects this button, a live feed video, a control panel which contains the trackbar for adjusting HSV values, a threshold image which represents the changes in the calibration of the HSV values, and another frame which contains a button named "SAVE VALUES" appears. When the user clicks the Save Values button, it saves whatever the values that have been set in the trackbar into a textfile.

My problem is, whenever i click that button, it does not perform what it is intended to do, which is to save the HSV values in a txtfile.

Here is the main code which is responsible for creating the additional frame when the user selects the Calibrate Button.

```
void TemplateFrame::OncalibTrackerButtonClick(wxCommandEvent& event)
{

    **some code for initializing the live video feed, the trackbars, etc.**

     CalibrationWindow* calibWindow =  new CalibrationWindow(this);
     calibWindow->setHSVvalues(H_MIN,S_MIN,V_MIN,H_MAX,S_MAX,V_MAX);

     calibrationModeTracker = true;

     **the following code after this line would be a pseudocode of what I am doing once the button has been click already
     while(calibrationModeTracker){
         calibWindow->Show(); // shows the "SAVE VALUES" frame
         wxYield();

         read live feed video
         createTrackbars();

         show live feed video
         show threshold image

     }
}
```

Inside the while loop, users would be able to click the "SAVE VALUES" button which would save the HSV values in a txtfile.

On the other hand, here is the event handler function of the newly created frame (CalibrationWindow.cpp) after clicking Calibrate Button which contains the Save Values button

```
    void CalibrationWindow::OnSaveClick(wxCommandEvent& event)
    {
      ofstream myfile;
      stringstream oss(stringstream::in | stringstream::out);
      string f;
      f = "//home//ianlangley//Desktop//Savefiles//HSVvalues_left.txt";
      f = f.append(oss.str());
      myfile.open(f.c_str());
      if (myfile.is_open()){

        myfile<<CalibrationWindow::getlow_H()<<"\n";
        myfile<<CalibrationWindow::getlow_S()<<"\n";
        myfile<<CalibrationWindow::getlow_V()<<"\n";
        myfile<<CalibrationWindow::gethigh_H()<<"\n";
        myfile<<CalibrationWindow::gethigh_S()<<"\n";
        myfile<<CalibrationWindow::gethigh_V();
        myfile.close();
     }
   }
```

Lastly, here is the code inside the header file: CalibrationWindow.h

```
    class CalibrationWindow: public wxFrame
    {
       public:

       CalibrationWindow(wxWindow* parent,wxWindowID id=wxID_ANY);
       virtual ~CalibrationWindow();
       void setHSVvalues(int lowH,int lowS, int lowV,int highH,int highS, int highV);
       int getlow_H();
       int getlow_S();
       int getlow_V();

       int gethigh_H();
       int gethigh_S();
       int gethigh_V();

       //(*Declarations(CalibrationWindow)
       wxButton* LeftHandButton;
       wxButton* RightHandButton;
       //*)

       protected:

        //(*Identifiers(CalibrationWindow)
        static const long ID_BUTTON2;
        static const long ID_BUTTON1;
        //*)

        private:
        int lowH,lowS,lowV,highH,highS,highV;
        //(*Handlers(CalibrationWindow)
        void OnRightHandButtonClick(wxCommandEvent& event);
        void OnLeftHandButtonClick(wxCommandEvent& event);
        //*)

        DECLARE_EVENT_TABLE()
};
```

Thank you to those who will be able to help me with this problem.

Comment: It's unclear what exactly is not working. Is `CalibrationWindow::OnSaveClick` never called? Is the file not written? Is it written but contains wrong values?

Comment: In a way, CalibrationWindow::OnSaveClick does not seem to work, so the file is not written.

Comment: So you know that `CalibrationWindow::OnSaveClick` is called. Good. Does `myfile.is_open()` return true? Does the path exist on your file system? You should learn to use a debugger to see what lines in your code are actually executed. Or at the very least, add some `wxMessageBox` calls to see what's going on ("a poor man's debugger"). There is nothing wrong with the code you are showing, as far as I can see.